# How to send and receive Emoji to webservice

Tags: android, emoji, emotion

I need to use emoji for chat in my android application.I'm using this library https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon to get emoji, its perfectly shows emoji but how can I send/receive to the server for my chat application.
Thanks-

This is my code for getting Emoji with the help of library

```
   <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmojicon"
            android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmojicon"
            android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"
            emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It shows emoji in EditText and TextView but issue is how can I get this emoji to send/receieve it to the server.I know I need to get Unicode but issue is how can I get Unicode from this Textview or EditText??

Comment: Just send a unicode of it and parse it on the other side

Comment: I don't get it. You want to send the text or the unicode only? Because as I said on my answer you just have to send the whole text. Just do getText() and send it to the server.

Comment: I want to get "I \ue32d emojicon" from editText but it returns "I oo emojiicon". just tell me how can I get something like this "I \ue32d emojicon" because getText()  doesn't work.

Comment: If your server receives bytes just send the bytes and it will work. Show us how are you sending the data to your server. Since that unicode is not readable text you won't be able to debug it normally. That's why you get that character.

Comment: String[] getFeedsParam = new String[]{ "user_id",user_id,"token",token1,"friend_id",friendId,"message",
    message1,URL
  };
this is my request parameters all are strings.I add them in nameValuePair and send it to the server.

Comment: That should work. Just send the data like that. If your server is properly done it should handle the unicode just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Emojis are just unicode. As you can see on that library: `android:text="I \ue32d emojicon"` where `ue32d`stands for that heart emoji.

More on unicode emojis: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

So you can simple send the text to your server and on the other side display it normally and it should be rendered as an image.

Comment: Yes I know I need to send Unicode to the server. How to the get Unicode and text from a EmojiconEditText? For example I wrote " I love (rainIcon)"

Comment: I don't think that's how you use this library. If you get the text of emojiedittext does it have the unicode or the `(rainIcon)`?

Comment: no It does not show unicode of the (rainIcon) but it shows in Library's TextView and its shows in Toast as well.I'm worried how can I get its unicode?

Comment: Please update your question and add the relevant code so we can be of more assistance.

Comment: I found answer of this question.I unescaped java String and it gave me unicode.

Comment: @RobinRoyal what u did plz post as answer , i didnt understood your comment above